# How do I return a boost::asio::deferred from a virtual function

Tags: templates, c++17, boost-asio

[Simplified example](https://godbolt.org/z/4oaMWWccW) for the question below:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
using namespace boost;


std::error_code do_run(int run){
    asio::io_context ctx{};
    asio::steady_timer timer1(ctx);
    timer1.expires_after(std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(300 - (run*100)));
    auto defer1 = timer1.async_wait(asio::deferred);

    std::error_code res{};
    defer1([run,&res](auto &&ec){
        std::cout << "Finished " << run << " " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        res = ec;
    });
    std::cout << "Prepare run " << run << " " << std::endl;
    ctx.run();
    std::cout << "Return to main " << run << " " << std::endl;
    return res;
}

auto do_run2(asio::io_context &ctx, int run){ // <- is there a generic type signature here?
    auto timer1 = std::make_shared<asio::steady_timer>(ctx);
    timer1->expires_after(std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(300 - (run*100)));
    return timer1->async_wait(asio::append(asio::deferred,std::move(timer1)));
}


int main(){
    asio::io_context main_context{};
    for(int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++){
        std::cout << "Run result {" << do_run(idx) << "}" << std::endl;
    }
    for(int idx2 = 0; idx2 < 3; idx2++){
        do_run2(main_context,idx2)([idx2](auto &&ec, auto &&tm){
            std::cout << "Run result deferred " << idx2 << " {" << ec << "}" << std::endl;
        });
    }
    main_context.run();
}
```

I have some code that is calling an interface method that uses Boost Asio calls internally.  Right now it returns an error code, but it blocks until completion.  I really want to pass in a completion token but since templates cannot be virtual that is not an option. The function `do_run` is the moral equivalent of what I have now.

I am able to use `asio::use_future` for a generic return and that works (save for the new thread every time).  Currently `asio::use_awaitable` is not an option.  Until then I was looking at `asio::deferred` as a completion token.  That would allow for some flexibility when coroutines are then an option. The example `do_run2` is what I am thinking.  If I play games with `decltype()` and copy/paste the result type from vscode's code completion I get this insane template expansion.  So my question in the end is how can I get a generic return type so that can be made a virtual method?

Comment: "save for the new thread every time" - what new thread?

Comment: It is my impression that prior to unified executors (c++23?) that it is only a thread.

Answer (score 3):

> So my question in the end is how can I get a generic return type so that can be made a virtual method?

### Background

Beware, while this may have limited use. All associated entities (executor, allocator, cancellation_slots, more?) will all need to be delegated, with type-erasure.

The completion tokens concept aims to

1. have zero-overhead abstraction by building all parameterization into the type system
2. have the same function template support *syntactically different* call sites

Even though 1. has less appeal if type-erase it, there are valid reasons to hiding all completion tokens by type-erasure: compilation firewalling (e.g. pimpl idiom).

Note that if you want to retain the call-site syntactical variation (including support for e.g. `use_awaitable`) you will always need a "trampoline" template function to dispatch into your type-erased interface.

### The Good News: `any_completion_handler`

There is some very recent work to implement a type erased `any_completion_handler`¹. It was [recently added](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/commit/64448e6a192c4206ac72720a7dd882c970c42666) to the `develop` branch²

There is an example

- in c++11 https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp11_examples.type_erasure
- in c++20 https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp20_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp20_examples.type_erasure

[image]

### Applying To Your Code

Your type-erased implementation could look like:

```
extern void do_run_impl(asio::any_completion_handler<void(error_code)> handler,
                        asio::any_io_executor ex, int run);
```

You would typically add an initiating function template like:

```
template <typename Token>
inline auto async_do_run(asio::any_io_executor ex, int run, Token&& token) {
    return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code)>(
        do_run_impl, token, std::move(ex), run);
}
```

Now you can use it in every way:

```
asio::awaitable<void> coro(int run) {
    try {
        co_await async_do_run(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, run,
                              asio::use_awaitable);
        std::cout << "async operation using co_await completed successfully" << std::endl;
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        std::cout << "async operation resulted in error: " << se.code().message()
                  << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T> bool is_ready(std::future<T> const& f) {
    return (f.wait_for(0ms) == std::future_status::ready);
}

int main(){
    asio::thread_pool ioc;
    auto ex = make_strand(ioc);

    std::future<void> fut = async_do_run(ex, 0, asio::use_future);

    asio::co_spawn(ex, coro(1), asio::detached);

    async_do_run(ex, 2, [](error_code ec) {
        std::cout << "callback completed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    });

    std::cout << "ready? " << std::boolalpha << is_ready(fut) << std::endl;

    fut.wait();
    std::cout << "ready? " << std::boolalpha << is_ready(fut) << std::endl;

    ioc.join();
}
```

To make it link, you have to make sure some TU defines the implementation function, e.g.:

```
void do_run_impl(asio::any_completion_handler<void(error_code)> handler,
                 asio::any_io_executor ex, int run) //
{
    auto tim = std::make_shared<asio::steady_timer>(ex, 300ms - run * 100ms);
    tim->async_wait(
        [tim, h = std::move(handler)](error_code ec) mutable { std::move(h)(ec); });
}
```

Note, though, that you can also use to brand-new `asio::consign` token adaptor to write it more succinctly:

```
auto timer = std::make_shared<asio::steady_timer>(ex, 300ms - run * 100ms);
timer->async_wait(asio::consign(std::move(handler), timer));
```

It will print:

```
ready? false
callback completed: Success
async operation using co_await completed successfully
ready? true
```

### Live Demo

No online compilers has Boost develop, so here's the listing and local demo:

**Live On Coliru**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/append.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;

extern void do_run_impl(asio::any_completion_handler<void(error_code)> handler,
                        asio::any_io_executor ex, int run);

template <typename Token>
inline auto async_do_run(asio::any_io_executor ex, int run, Token&& token) {
    return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code)>(
        do_run_impl, token, std::move(ex), run);
}

asio::awaitable<void> coro(int run) {
    try {
        co_await async_do_run(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, run,
                              asio::use_awaitable);
        std::cout << "async operation using co_await completed successfully" << std::endl;
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        std::cout << "async operation resulted in error: " << se.code().message()
                  << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T> bool is_ready(std::future<T> const& f) {
    return (f.wait_for(0ms) == std::future_status::ready);
}

int main(){
    asio::thread_pool ioc;
    auto ex = make_strand(ioc);

    std::future<void> fut = async_do_run(ex, 0, asio::use_future);

    asio::co_spawn(ex, coro(1), asio::detached);

    async_do_run(ex, 2, [](error_code ec) {
        std::cout << "callback completed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    });

    std::cout << "ready? " << std::boolalpha << is_ready(fut) << std::endl;

    fut.wait();
    std::cout << "ready? " << std::boolalpha << is_ready(fut) << std::endl;

    ioc.join();
}

void do_run_impl(asio::any_completion_handler<void(error_code)> handler,
                 asio::any_io_executor ex, int run) {
    auto timer = std::make_shared<asio::steady_timer>(ex, 300ms - run * 100ms);
    timer->async_wait(asio::consign(std::move(handler), timer));
}
```

Running locally:

[image]

---

¹ branch from here https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/1100#issuecomment-1205062267

² beware: there were fixes as recent as [Wed Dec 7 07:34:26 2022 +1100](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/commit/7811479a80dee80b5fa086d38e171f1c4a4608fb); That's less than 2 days ago at the time of this writing. You will want to keep an eye on updates

Comment: I got so carried away by the presence of the new-fangled `any_completion_handler` that I perhaps forget to point out the obvious: This being a static signature it can obviously be part of a virtual signature.

Comment: It is static, but my poor primate brain is struggling to "unwrap" it for a return type.  Right now I am abusing the vscode tooltip over the `auto` and copy/paste that monstrosity :(

Comment: The only static interface (the part that you might virtualize) returns a void. That’s the key: the token dependent behaviour is erased into a callable argument. (Maybe your comment wasn’t in reaction to the answer code?)