# Recommended way to use Boost socket / serial_port classes similarly using the same code?

Tags: c++, tcp, serial-port, boost-asio

The project I'm working on is largely an effort to learn modern C++ and wxWidgets GUI implementation while building an app that will solve some problems I deal with daily. I need connectivity to TCP, UDP, and/or RS232, receiving plain ASCII data on each, with an indefinite count and variety connections active simultaneously. I dug up some tcp client and rs232 code on Github to work from and got a proof-of-concept working.

Then I replaced most of that using Boost since I kept running into suggestions to use Boost on every SO answer. It includes all the connectivity I'm looking for - currently `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` and `boost::asio::serial_port`, I haven't looked into UDP yet.

I kept having to make changes in multiple places when something in the handling changed. In attempting to `DRY` it, I haven't been able to find an optimal way to use these classes in the same code, despite the fact that they have very similar interfaces. I was surprised they don't seem to inherit from some common 'stream' class. They use the identical syntax for synchronous read/writes.

I haven't had success writing a unified function to open a connection and run the worker thread for each connection. I've made multiple attempts at templates, `boost::any` return type, `std::variant` return type,  `void*`, and `union`. I've been writing and rewriting this all day, but most of my attempts I didn't really understand in the first place.

My code to receive, re-buffer, and process the data is working mostly as I'd like:

```
template <class Handle>
bool receiveData(Handle& handle){
    std::string line_buffer("");
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer(SERIAL_BUF_SIZE);

    std::size_t bytes_transferred = 
        boost::asio::read(handle, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error);
    if(error && error !=boost::asio::error::eof){
        std::cout << "\x1b[31;1mError receiving data\x1b[0m" << std::endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        const char* temp_data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(receive_buffer.data());
        std::string new_data(temp_data, temp_data+bytes_transferred);
        receive_buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
        persistent_buffer << new_data;
        persistent_buffer >> std::ws;
        while(std::getline(persistent_buffer, line_buffer, '\r')){
            if(persistent_buffer.eof()) break;
            persistent_buffer >> std::ws;
            if(not line_buffer.empty()){
                updateLiveData(line_buffer);
                line_buffer.clear();
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        }
        if(persistent_buffer.eof()){
            persistent_buffer.clear();
            persistent_buffer.str({});
            persistent_buffer << line_buffer;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

It seems like there is a way to make something like the following code, using socket and serial_port in a roughly interchangeable way, but I'm not experienced enough to find it. My naive implementation is working but I have two distinct functions that differ only in the lines related to opening the connection.

```
while(not this->mustDie.load()){
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::system::error_code error;

    /*  The tcp function is identical except for this section */
    boost::asio::serial_port port(io_service);
    port.open("COM"+com_num, error);
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(stoi(baudrate)));
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(error) {
        std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        continue;
        }

    boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer(QUERY), error);

    while(receiveData(port) and not this->mustDie.load()){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I kept having to make changes in multiple places when something in the handling changed. In attempting to DRY it, I haven't been able to find an optimal way to use these classes in the same code, despite the fact that they have very similar interfaces. I was surprised they don't seem to inherit from some common 'stream' class. They use the identical syntax for synchronous read/writes.

This is because modern C++ design favors static polymorphism over dynamic polymorphism. The upshot is that the compiler can optimize way more for your specific use-case. In effect, inlining everything as if all virtual calls could be devirtualized, because no static type information is ever lost¹.

The genericity multiplies because Asio **also** generalizes on the way in which you compose your asynchronous operations. You might want to use the old-fashioned callback style, or you may prefer C++20 coroutines, using `std::future` or indeed your own custom `async_result` implementation. You might want to decorate these to use cancellation slots, tell Asio to use a custom allocator for services that require it, return errors in a tuple instead of throwing exceptions etc. etc.

The design of Asio makes it so that all of these are supported with a single initiation function. Because of all the static polymorphism the compiler can and will inline away unnecessary overhead, meaning that you don't pay for what you don't use.

In addition, dynamic polymorphism often implies allocation overhead (e.g. a collection of polymorphic "Streams" will typically have to dynamically allocate its elements).

### Is It Better? (*But, My Use Case...*)

Of course, in your case you might be more interested in the user-friendly common interface.

Given a generic library design like Asio's you **can** make it so. The reverse is not true (e.g. given Poco::Net, Qt Networking or Wx) **imposes** the overhead, and there's no way to remove it.

This makes Asio strictly more applicable and general purpose, at the cost of having a higher learning curve. I would argue that this is exactly the C++ spirit, so it's all good.

For the sake of "show don't tell" let me demonstrate how you might implement the common interface. Let's target the [`AsyncStream` concept](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/stream_types.html):

### Making It So: Using Static Polymorphism

Using static polymorphism you might define a simple line-wise echo-server like so:

```
template<typename AsyncStream>
struct EchoSession : std::enable_shared_from_this<EchoSession<AsyncStream>>
{
    EchoSession(AsyncStream stream)
        : _stream(std::move(stream))
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        do_echo_loop();
    }

private:
    using std::enable_shared_from_this<EchoSession<AsyncStream> >::shared_from_this;

    static void fail(error_code ec)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error " << ec.message() << " at " << ec.location() << std::endl;
    }

    void do_echo_loop()
    {
        asio::async_read_until(
            _stream,
            _buffer,
            "\n",
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n)
            {
                if(ec && ec != asio::error::eof) // eof is to be expected
                    return fail(ec);

                if(n > 0)
                {
                    auto text = buffer_cast<char const*>(_buffer.data());
                    std::cout << "Got " << n << " (" << ec.message() << ") "
                              << quoted(std::string(text, n - 1)) << std::endl;

                    asio::async_write(
                        _stream,
                        asio::buffer(text, n),
                        [this, self, n](error_code ec, size_t m)
                        {
                            if(ec)
                                return fail(ec);
                            assert(m == n);
                            _buffer.consume(m);
                            do_echo_loop(); // next line please
                        });
                }
            });
    }

    AsyncStream _stream;
    asio::streambuf _buffer;
};
```

Now you can run EchoSession on any type that models `AsyncStream`, e.g.

```
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
using asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    asio::thread_pool io(10);

    // let's create a TCP client
    tcp::socket s(make_strand(io));
    s.connect({{}, 8989}); // talk to localhost:8989

    // we can use EchoSession regardless of implementation
    make_session(std::move(s))->run();

    // and open serial ports
    for(auto dev : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc))
    {
        asio::serial_port sp(make_strand(io), dev);
        sp.set_option(asio::serial_port::baud_rate(115200)); // etc

        make_session(std::move(sp))->run();
    }

    // wait for all sessions to complete/fail
    io.join();
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07e57363fa7f7df4)** or locally demonstrating a serial port emulated with `socat`:

[image]

### The Real Deal: Using Virtual Interfaces

Let's create a type-erased interface for `IAsyncStream` instead. We'll be using
the recent `any_completion_handler` feature² so we can leverage all completion
tokens with full fidelity.

```
struct IAsyncStream {
    using Handler = asio::any_completion_handler<void(error_code, size_t)>;
    virtual void async_read_some_impl(Handler, asio::mutable_buffer) = 0;
    virtual void async_write_some_impl(Handler, asio::const_buffer)  = 0;
};
```

In fact, to make it on par with the earlier demo, let's add executor support as well, and the virtual destructor we'll need:

```
struct IAsyncStream {
    using Handler = asio::any_completion_handler<void(error_code, size_t)>;
    using Exec    = asio::any_io_executor;

    virtual Exec get_executor()                                      = 0;
    virtual void async_read_some_impl(Handler, asio::mutable_buffer) = 0;
    virtual void async_write_some_impl(Handler, asio::const_buffer)  = 0;
    virtual ~IAsyncStream()                                          = default;
};
```

Now, we will be able to wrap implementations:

```
template <typename Impl> struct Wrap : IAsyncStream {
    Impl _stream;

    explicit Wrap(Impl s) : _stream(std::move(s)) {}

    virtual Exec get_executor() override {
        return _stream.get_executor();
    }
    virtual void async_read_some_impl(Handler h, asio::mutable_buffer b) override {
        return _stream.async_read_some(b, std::move(h));
    }
    virtual void async_write_some_impl(Handler h, asio::const_buffer b) override {
        return _stream.async_write_some(b, std::move(h));
    }
};
```

That's already pretty trivial, but let's hide all the implementation details in a type named `AnyStream` which also does the generic initiation functions:

```
struct AnyStream {
    template <typename Impl> AnyStream(Impl impl) : _impl(std::make_unique<Wrap<Impl>>(std::move(impl))) {}

    template <typename Token> auto async_read_some(asio::mutable_buffer b, Token&& token) {
        return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code, size_t)>(
            std::bind(&IAsyncStream::async_read_some_impl, _impl.get(), _1, _2), token, b);
    }

    template <typename Token> auto async_write_some(asio::const_buffer b, Token&& token) {
        return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code, size_t)>(
            std::bind(&IAsyncStream::async_write_some_impl, _impl.get(), _1, _2), token, b);
    }

  private:
    struct IAsyncStream {
        // as above
    };

    template <typename Impl> struct Wrap : IAsyncStream {
        // as above
    };

    std::unique_ptr<IAsyncStream> _impl;
};
```

Now we have a polymorphic stream wrapper that behaves like a value type. We could use it like:

```
tcp::socket s(make_strand(io));

AnyStream ss(std::move(s));
std::string b(10, '\0');
ss.async_read_some(asio::buffer(b), asio::detached);
```

Or indeed, we can implement the entire `EchoSession` using it. Note that it no longer need to be a template, since all the polymorphism has been erased through `IAsyncStream`:

### Full Demo Using Type-Erased `IAsyncStream`

**[Live On Compiler Explorer³](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/ceqsr15nb)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct AnyStream {
    template <typename Impl> AnyStream(Impl impl) : _impl(std::make_unique<Wrap<Impl>>(std::move(impl))) {}

    using executor_type = asio::any_io_executor;
    executor_type get_executor() { return _impl->get_executor(); }

    template <typename Token> auto async_read_some(asio::mutable_buffer b, Token&& token) {
        return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code, size_t)>(
            std::bind(&IAsyncStream::async_read_some_impl, _impl.get(), _1, _2), token, b);
    }

    template <typename Token> auto async_write_some(asio::const_buffer b, Token&& token) {
        return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code, size_t)>(
            std::bind(&IAsyncStream::async_write_some_impl, _impl.get(), _1, _2), token, b);
    }

private:
    struct IAsyncStream {
        using Handler = asio::any_completion_handler<void(error_code, size_t)>;
        using Exec    = executor_type;

        virtual Exec get_executor()                                      = 0;
        virtual void async_read_some_impl(Handler, asio::mutable_buffer) = 0;
        virtual void async_write_some_impl(Handler, asio::const_buffer)  = 0;
        virtual ~IAsyncStream()                                          = default;
    };

    template <typename Impl> struct Wrap : IAsyncStream {
        Impl _stream;

        explicit Wrap(Impl s) : _stream(std::move(s)) {}

        virtual Exec get_executor() override { //
            return _stream.get_executor();
        }
        virtual void async_read_some_impl(Handler h, asio::mutable_buffer b) override {
            return _stream.async_read_some(b, std::move(h));
        }
        virtual void async_write_some_impl(Handler h, asio::const_buffer b) override {
            return _stream.async_write_some(b, std::move(h));
        }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<IAsyncStream> _impl;
};

struct EchoSession : std::enable_shared_from_this<EchoSession> {
    EchoSession(AnyStream stream) : _stream(std::move(stream)) {}

    void run() { do_echo_loop(); }

private:
    static void fail(error_code ec) {
        std::cerr << "Error " << ec.message() << " at " << ec.location() << std::endl;
    }

    void do_echo_loop() {
        asio::async_read_until( //
            _stream, _buffer, "\n", [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                if (ec && ec != asio::error::eof) // eof is to be expected
                    return fail(ec);

                if (n > 0) {
                    auto text = buffer_cast<char const*>(_buffer.data());
                    std::cout << "Got " << n << " (" << ec.message() << ") "
                            << quoted(std::string(text, n - 1)) << std::endl;

                    asio::async_write( //
                        _stream, asio::buffer(text, n), [this, self, n](error_code ec, size_t m) {
                            if (ec)
                                return fail(ec);
                            assert(m == n);
                            _buffer.consume(m);
                            do_echo_loop(); // next line please
                        });
                }
            });
    }

    AnyStream       _stream;
    asio::streambuf _buffer;
};

#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
using asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    asio::thread_pool io(10);

    // let's create a TCP client
    tcp::socket s(make_strand(io));
    s.connect({{}, 8989}); // talk to localhost:8989

    // we can use EchoSession regardless of implementation
    std::make_shared<EchoSession>(std::move(s))->run();

    // and open serial ports
    for(auto dev : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc))
    {
        asio::serial_port sp(make_strand(io), dev);
        sp.set_option(asio::serial_port::baud_rate(115200)); // etc

        std::make_shared<EchoSession>(std::move(sp))->run();
    }

    // wait for all sessions to complete/fail
    io.join();
}
```

Again, the live demo to show it off:

[image]

---

¹ assuming you don't use a type-erasing helper like `any_io_executor` or `any_completion_handler` (new in boost 1.81.0)

² see [How do I return a boost::asio::deferred from a virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745728/how-do-i-return-a-boostasiodeferred-from-a-virtual-function/74748783#74748783)

³ Coliru uses an older version of boost

Comment: Just as a sidenote: the full-blown support with `any_completion_handler` is probably not required in end-user code. I mean, just choose a completion method :) E.g. I would chose C++20 coros, and write it all without any special treatment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd08d332d4deb6c7 - it's by far the shortest, most readable, probably more efficient as well. My local demo https://imgur.com/a/1kYKlJ4